# MultiIndex isn't kept when pd.concating multiple subtotal rows

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I lose my multiIndex when I try to pd.concat a second subtotal. I'm able to add the first subtotal but not the second which is a sum of B0.

This is how my current df is:

```
lvl0                    a         b     
lvl1                  bar  foo  bah  foo
A0 B0 C0 D0             1    0    3    2
         D1             5    4    7    6
         First Total    6    4   10    8
      C1 D0             9    8   11   10
         D1            13   12   15   14
         First Total   22   20   26   24
      C2 D0            17   16   19   18
```

After trying to add the second subtotal I get this:

```
lvl0                            a           b      
lvl1                          bar   foo   bah   foo
(A0, B0, C2, First Total)    38    36    42    40
(A0, B0, C3, D0)             25    24    27    26
(A0, B0, C3, D1)             29    28    31    30
(A0, B0, C3, First Total)    54    52    58    56
(A0, B0, Second Total)      120   112   136   128
(A0, B1, C0, D0)             33    32    35    34
(A0, B1, C0, D1)             37    36    39    38
(A0, B1, C0, First Total)    70    68    74    72
(A0, B1, C1, D0)             41    40    43    42
```

You should be able to copy and paste the code below to test

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# creating multiIndex
def mklbl(prefix, n):
    return ["%s%s" % (prefix, i) for i in range(n)]


miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A', 4),
                                        mklbl('B', 2),
                                        mklbl('C', 4),
                                        mklbl('D', 2)])


micolumns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'foo'), ('a', 'bar'),
                                        ('b', 'foo'), ('b', 'bah')],
                                      names=['lvl0', 'lvl1'])


dfmi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(miindex) * len(micolumns))
                     .reshape((len(miindex), len(micolumns))),
                    index=miindex,
                   columns=micolumns).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)

# My code STARTS HERE
# creating the first subtotal
print(dfmi.index)
df1 = dfmi.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).sum()
df2 = dfmi.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()

df1 = df1.set_index(np.array(['First Total'] * len(df1)), append=True)
dfmi = pd.concat([dfmi, df1]).sort_index(level=[0, 1])

print(dfmi)

# this is where the multiIndex is lost
df2 = df2.set_index(np.array(['Second Total'] * len(df2)), append=True)
dfmi = pd.concat([dfmi, df2]).sort_index(level=[1])

print(dfmi)
```

How I would want it to look:

```
lvl0                    a         b     
lvl1                  bar  foo  bah  foo
A0 B0 C0 D0             1    0    3    2
         D1             5    4    7    6
         First Total    6    4   10    8
      C1 D0             9    8   11   10
         D1            13   12   15   14
         First Total   22   20   26   24
      C2 D0            17   16   19   18
         D1            21   20   23   22
         First Total   38   36   42   40
      C3 D0            25   24   27   26
         D1            29   28   31   30
         First Total   54   52   58   56
      Second Total     120  112  136  128
   B1 C0 D0            33   32   35   34
         D1            37   36   39   38
         First Total   70   68   74   72
      C1 D0            41   40   43   42
         D1            45   44   47   46
         First Total   86   84   90   88
      C2 D0            49   48   51   50
         D1            53   52   55   54
         First Total  102  100  106  104
      C3 D0            57   56   59   58
         D1            61   60   63   62
         First Total  118  116  122  120
       Second Total   376  368  392  384
```

the first total is sum of level 2,
the second total is sum of level 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dfmi` has a 4-level MultiIndex:

```
In [208]: dfmi.index.nlevels
Out[208]: 4
```

`df2` has a 3-level MultiIndex. Instead, if you use

```
df2 = df2.set_index([np.array(['Second Total'] * len(df2)), [''] * len(df2)], append=True)
```

then `df2` ends up with a 4-level MultiIndex. When `dfmi` and `df2` have the same number of levels,
 then `pd.concat([dfmi, df2])` produces the desired result.

---

One problem you may face when sorting by index labels is that it relies on the strings `'First'` and `'Second'`
appearing last in alphabetic order. An alterative to sorting by index would be assigning a numeric `order` column
and sorting by that instead:

```
dfmi['order'] = range(len(dfmi))
df1['order'] = dfmi.groupby(level=[0,1,2])['order'].last() + 0.1
df2['order'] = dfmi.groupby(level=[0,1])['order'].last() + 0.2
...
dfmi = pd.concat([dfmi, df1, df2])        
dfmi = dfmi.sort_values(by='order')
```

---

Incorporating [Scott Boston's improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56450982/190597), the code would then look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def mklbl(prefix, n):
    return ["%s%s" % (prefix, i) for i in range(n)]


miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A', 4),
                                        mklbl('B', 2),
                                        mklbl('C', 4),
                                        mklbl('Z', 2)])


micolumns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'foo'), ('a', 'bar'),
                                        ('b', 'foo'), ('b', 'bah')],
                                      names=['lvl0', 'lvl1'])


dfmi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(miindex) * len(micolumns))
                     .reshape((len(miindex), len(micolumns))),
                    index=miindex,
                   columns=micolumns).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)

df1 = dfmi.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).sum()
df2 = dfmi.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()

dfmi['order'] = range(len(dfmi))
df1['order'] = dfmi.groupby(level=[0,1,2])['order'].last() + 0.1
df2['order'] = dfmi.groupby(level=[0,1])['order'].last() + 0.2

df1 = df1.assign(lev4='First').set_index('lev4', append=True)
df2 = df2.assign(lev3='Second', lev4='').set_index(['lev3','lev4'], append=True)
dfmi = pd.concat([dfmi, df1, df2])
dfmi = dfmi.sort_values(by='order')
dfmi = dfmi.drop(['order'], axis=1)
print(dfmi)
```

which yields

```
lvl0                  a         b     
lvl1                bar  foo  bah  foo
A0 B0 C0     Z0       1    0    3    2
             Z1       5    4    7    6
             First    6    4   10    8
      C1     Z0       9    8   11   10
             Z1      13   12   15   14
             First   22   20   26   24
      C2     Z0      17   16   19   18
             Z1      21   20   23   22
             First   38   36   42   40
      C3     Z0      25   24   27   26
             Z1      29   28   31   30
             First   54   52   58   56
      Second        120  112  136  128
...
```

Answer (score 2):

@unutbu points out the nature of the problem.   df2 has three levels of a multiindex and you need a 4th level.

I would use `assign` and `set_index` to create that fourth level:

```
df2 = df2.assign(lev3='Second Total', lev4='').set_index(['lev3','lev4'], append=True)
```

This avoids calculating the length of the dataframe.